# How can I animate the textColor of an NSTextField?

Tags: swift, cocoa, animation, nstextfield

I have an NSTextField that is acting as the display for a clock. At any given time it displays something like: `10:42:22`

The background of the window changes color. Sometimes it's a light background and sometimes it's dark. Right now, the text color changes so it's visible on the background, but it's instant. I'd like it to fade.

This seems to work well when I use a `CATransition` and set the `textColor`. However, it also fades the string of text itself. Imagine `10:42:22` cross fading into `10:42:23`. I'd like the string to continue to change instantly, like a digital clock, while the color fades smoothly.

I've also tried:

```
animator().textColor = someOtherColor
```

but this doesn't seem to have any effect. The color continues to change, but it does not fade from one to the next.

Here's a quick mockup of the effect I'm looking for from the text.

[image: text changing color]

Comment: I don't really understand your question.  Your mean, you want the text color to gradually turn itself from red into blue?

Comment: @ElTomato I added an image to help explain.

Comment: That's not difficult.  Have two text fields showing the time code.  Then change the alpha of the top field with NSAnimationContext.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
    private func animateTitleColor(selected: Bool, completion: (()->())?) {
        if !selected{
            NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ (context) in
                context.duration = self.animationInterval
                self.titleLabel.animator().textColor = rgb(red: 197, green: 191, blue: 196)
            }, completionHandler: completion)
        }else{
            NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ (context) in
                context.duration = self.animationInterval
                self.titleLabel.animator().textColor = .white
            }, completionHandler: completion)
        }
    }
```

`titleLabel` is declared like this: `let titleLabel = NSTextField()`

Comment: it also worked with NSTextField attributedText property ? 
cause I test in my side and it did not.